# Interpreting standard errors of linear regression with logged dependent variable

Tags: interpretation, standard-error, logarithm

I'm running a linear regression with a logged dependent variable. This is the only variable in the model that is logged. For interpretation, I've exponentiated the coefficients, subtracted one, and then multiplied by 100, giving the percent increase (or decrease).

I'd like to present these numbers in a table because just giving the raw coefficients doesn't seem as helpful. My question is, how can I present the standard errors? They wouldn't make much sense next to the percentages, so I'm wondering what the appropriate transformation would be?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion - but can you make a table with three columns? One for the raw coefficients, one for the standard errors, and one for the interpretation?